# Converting all data to tables on all worksheets in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 84 worksheets all with different amounts of rows of data.
I need to convert all of the worksheets data to tables.

I found this macro online which I thought would work if I had all of the sheets selected but it doesn't.

```
Sub A_SelectAllMakeTable2()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection, , xlYes)
    tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium15"
End Sub
```

Is there a way to modify this so it will affect the entire workbook?

Comment: Does the data start in A1 on every sheet?

Comment: Yes it does! the row 1 is headers as well, if that helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
Sub A_SelectAllMakeTable2()
    Dim ws as worksheet
    for each ws in activeworkbook.worksheets
    ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ws.range("A1").Currentregion, , xlYes).TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium15"
    next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: amazing! Thank you so much!! :)